# how to create an interactive column selection panel for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-interface, interactive

I have a dataframe with long column names and would like to use GUI to select columns of interest instead of typing names some of which may have spaces etc so not tab completion friendly. Is there any example code to do that in vscode using notebook?

Comment: I was responding to a now-deleted comment criticizing the fact that you answered your own question. I think your question and answer are valid (at least on the form, I didn't check the logic). The -1 are not mine.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to add a reproducible example, I'll be happy to test and to upvote if functional.

Answer (score -1):

after some trial and error, this code does the job by subclassing , this way you can enhance pd.DataFrame with additional custom utility functions

```
# create a subclass


import panel as pn

class myDataFrame (pd.DataFrame):
    """A class that creates a Panel panel that allows the user to select columns from a dataframe.

    Args:
        df: The dataframe to select columns from.

    Attributes:
        selected_df: The selected dataframe.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, df):
        import warnings
        super().__init__(df)
        # Disable the warning temporarily
       # Disable the warning
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
            
            self.df=df
            self.selected_df = None
            self.selected_columns = None
            self.column_checkboxes = [pn.widgets.Checkbox(name=column) for column in self.df.columns]

    def select_columns(self):
        """Selects the columns from the dataframe based on checkboxes' state.
        """

        # Get the selected columns from the checkbox widgets.
        selected_columns = [checkbox.name for checkbox in self.column_checkboxes if checkbox.value]

        # Create a new dataframe with the selected columns.
        self.selected_df = self.df[selected_columns]
        self.selected_columns = selected_columns

    def create_column_selection_panel(self):
        """Creates a Panel panel that allows the user to select columns from a dataframe.

        Returns:
        A Panel panel that allows the user to select columns from a dataframe.
        """

        # Create a row layout for the checkbox widgets.
        column_selection_row = pn.layout.Column(*self.column_checkboxes)

        # Create a button that will select the selected columns.
        
        select_columns_button = pn.widgets.Button(
            name="Select Columns",
            
            width=200,
            height=25,
        )

        # Connect the select columns button to the select columns function.
        select_columns_button.on_click(lambda event: self.select_columns())

        # Create a layout for the column selection panel.
        column_selection_panel = pn.layout.Column(
            column_selection_row,
            select_columns_button,
        )

        return column_selection_panel

    def get_selected_df(self):
        """Gets the selected dataframe.

        Returns:
        The selected dataframe.
        """

        return self.selected_df
# example usage -works in vscode jupyter notebook
newdf=myDataFrame(df)
newdf.create_column_selection_panel()
newdf.selected_columns
newdf.get_selected_df()
```